# How to get document file for uploading to services from iOS app

Tags: objective-c, iphone, file-upload, ios8, nsdocumentdirectory

All,
I need to upload a file to server, i have worked on services for uploading a file which working perfectly fine i have tested for png.

Now here i need to select doc,xml,txt file from my application.  since i can able to load photo gallery from  iOS app,  but struck with getting those doc,xml and txt formate file into my application.

how to get those documents like xml,doc, txt file in to my project app.  (Since photo library will not show those file.)  Is apple allow to access my local document folder.

Comment: There is no local document folder, files are saved per app and can only be accessed by that app. You might be able to register you app so that it can open the files or maybe you can use iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you get a list of files in your application directory.

```
// get the path of the application directory
NSString *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
        NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// Get a list of file at path
NSArray* files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path 
                                                                     error:nil];
```

Then you need to build an interface for user to pick files, navigate through folder, and upload to your server and etc.

Reference: [Working with Directories on iPhone OS](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_on_iPhone_OS), [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains)

**Edit:**

Unfortunately, iOS is different for other OS such as Android, or MacOS, or even Windows. It does not have a share Document folder for all apps. Contents such as xml, docs are saved under the document of each app. It may sounds weird if you never worked with iOS before. However, it is very handy to keep the phone clean. As long as an app is deleted, so will all the crapy data that it created.

However, you can still send data between applications, which is referred as [Inter-App Communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html). You will need to implement the following to handle the documents that was sent to your app:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
```

Also, it is also very important to know the [following](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html). In short, you will need to let your app know what data that it accepts. For example, Adobe App will take any .pdf files; while Dropbox App will take whatever file since they will get uploaded anyway.

> You need to register the document types that your application can open with iOS. To do this you need to add a document type to your app’s Info.plist for each document type that your app can open. Additionally if any of the document types are not known by iOS, you will need to provide an Uniform Type Identifier (UTI) for that document type.

You may need to read more about [Uniform Type Identifier (UTI)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/UniformTypeIdentifier.html) before you get started.

The about is more about receiving data. If you want a more complete understanding of the entire process, you may also take a look at how to send data to other applications as well. Two of the very important class that you could have a look are [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/index.html) and [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/).

Comment: so for application, download .xml, txt or doc file from email from iPhone will be added to application interface and used in services.  This is an approach to implement.

Comment: @kiran, I am a bit confused. Do you mean upload?

Comment: @kiran, Yay, unfortunately, different operating system have different behaviour. iOS is  different for android. It doesn't not have a share **Document** folder for all apps. Contents such as xml, docs are saved under the document of each app.

Comment: so i cannot upload xml document file which are using by another applications like adobe reader, mail etc.